# I am using cakephp 4.0. I try to upload image in cloudinary (Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile)

Tags: php, object, cakephp, cloudinary, image-upload

My Post data image return this format. why return this type. I want imagea array and upload a image in cloudinary how yo use it. could you any one can help..

```
Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile Object (
[clientFilename:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => IMG-20180705-WA0007.jpg
[clientMediaType:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
[error:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => 0
[file:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpB830.tmp
[moved:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => 
[size:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => 164593
[stream:Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile:private] => )
```

Answer (score 2):

As for the "*why*", file upload objects are more versatile, allow for easier testing, and provide a clean, standardized interface.

While you can switch back to using arrays by setting the `App.uploadedFilesAsObjects` configuration option to `false`, it doesn't seem that Cloudinary requires the usage of file upload arrays, their PHP SDK methods for uploading files accepts a simple local file path, ie you should be able to do:

```php
$tmpPath = $uploadedFile->getStream()->getMetadata('uri');
$result = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($tmpPath, [/* ... */]);
```

`$tmpPath` will be the same path that the upload array's `tmp` key would give you.

For a raw API call you'd probably use the binary file data to send it in a POST request, which you can easily access via the stream too:

```
$filePostData = $uploadedFile->getStream()->getContents();
```

That's basically the same as reading the file that the upload array's `tmp` key points to.

See also

- **[PSR-7: HTTP message interfaces > Uploaded Files](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#16-uploaded-files)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > File Uploads](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#file-uploads)**
- **[Cloudinary Documentation > Integrations > PHP SDK > PHP image and video upload](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_and_video_upload)**